# SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters

Tags: php, soap-client

I want to make soap call with this codes:

```
      $fields = array(
    "Token_param" => array(
        "AMOUNT" => $this->getEncryptedAmount(),
        "CRN" => $this->getEncryptedTrancactionId(),
        "MID" => $this->getEncryptedMerchantId(),
        "REFERALADRESS" => $this->getEncryptedCallbackUrl(),
        "SIGNATURE" => $this->createSignature(),
        "TID" => $this->getEncryptedTerminalId()
    )
);

try {
    $ops = array ('soap' => array(
        'attempts' => 2 // Attempts if soap connection is fail
    ) );
    $soap = new SoapClient($this->serverUrl,$ops, array("stream_context" => stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
            )
        )
    )));
    $response = $soap->reservation($fields);

} catch(\SoapFault $e) {
    $this->transactionFailed();
    $this->newLog('SoapFault', $e->getMessage());
    throw $e;
}
```

But I get:
SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters

I think I have problem with second arguments of soap client.

Comment: So whats in `$this->serverUrl`

Comment: I get the feeling you are confusing what parameter 2 is for [see the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: https://mabna.shaparak.ir/TokenService?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

The best way to construct the right request is to use a WSDL to php sdk which will guide you in order to construct the request. In addition, it'll help you handle the response.

You should take a look to the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.